# Does the tire DOT number describe the creation date or the certification date?

Tags: tires

I was under the impression that the DOT date on a tire describes the week of the year it was **created**. I was told by a tire salesman however that the **actual** creation date is only known by the manufacturer and instead the DOT code provides information about the date the tire was certified in or the date it left the factory or something similar and that the actual date of manufacture is not told to them by the manufacturer (e.g. Michelin).

Is he trying to pull a fast one on me or something (although this actually works against him but w/e ).

Comment: Quick google search : https://www.tirebuyer.com/education/how-to-determine-the-age-of-your-tires You need to improve your google-fu...

Comment: How would you add the DOT number *after* manufacture? It is part of the moulded shape of the tire itself!

Comment: @SolarMike I have obviously already viewed this page but getting the expected response made it even more suspicious and I wanted clarification.

Comment: If you always believe what a salesman says....

Comment: @SolarMike I always question it but I am also not audacious to believe I always know better than them

Comment: How could we know "I have obviously already viewed this page"???

Comment: The rules are clear. Research before asking a question. You should assume people follow the rules until proven different.

Answer (score 1):

The DOT number shows the week, year and place of manufacture.

It is required by the US as part of their standards DOT is Department of Transport...

See [enter link description here](https://www.tirebuyer.com/education/how-to-determine-the-age-of-your-tires)

Answer (score -1):

It's a manufacture date, not a certification date.

Comment: Can you post something, like a link (and the information in the link) which verifies this?

Comment: https://www.tirerack.com/tires/tiretech/techpage.jsp?techid=172